# Replace all spaces in a string with '%20'. Assume that the string has sufficient space at the end of the string to hold the additional characters

Tags: c, string, algorithm, replace, char

The question is as the titles, and I have write a code to implement this function. The code is as below, but the sentence: *(str+length_copy-1+tail_space_num) = *(str+length_copy-1); cause an error.
Could you give me a hand? Any kind of answer would be helpful!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

void replaceSpace(char* str){
if(str == NULL ){
    printf("The parameter is null pointer\n");
}else if(strlen(str) == 0){
    printf("The parameter you parse into is a empty string\n");
}else{
    int length,length_copy,space_num,tail_space_num;
    length=length_copy=strlen(str);
    space_num=tail_space_num =0;
    while(*(str + length -1) == ' '){//' ' is char, but " " is string
        tail_space_num++;
        length--;
    }

    length_copy = length;

    while(length-1>=0){
        if(*(str+length-1) == ' ')
            space_num++;
        length--;
    }
    printf("%d\n",length_copy);
    printf("%d\n",tail_space_num);
    printf("%d\n",space_num);
    if(space_num * 2 != tail_space_num){
        printf("In the tail of the string, there is not enough space!\n");
    }else{
        while((length_copy-1)>=0){
            if(*(str+length_copy-1)!=' '){
                *(str+length_copy-1+tail_space_num) = *(str+length_copy-1);
            }else{
                *(str+length_copy-1+tail_space_num) = '0';
                *(str+length_copy-2+tail_space_num) = '2';
                *(str+length_copy-3+tail_space_num) = '%';
                tail_space_num = tail_space_num -2;
            }
            length_copy --;
        }
    }   
}
} 

main(){
char* str = "Mr John Smith    ";
printf("The original string is: %s\n", str);
printf("the length of string is: %d\n", strlen(str));
replaceSpace(str);
printf("The replaced string is: %s\n", str);
system("pause");    
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I think there is a case in which area of the converted is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `str` is a pointer that is initialized to a string literal, which is read-only. You should instead pass in a writable array of `char` to the function.

```
char str[] = "Mr John Smith\0      ";
```

My proposed solution makes `str` an array instead that initialized with the contents of the NUL terminated string `"Mr John Smith"`, and some padding space characters following the NUL bytes (and the padding spaces are followed by another NUL).

Comment: You may want to point out that your code **copies** the string literal into the array (which I'm assuming is what happens), as opposed to the pointer approach, which merely makes `str` **point to** the string literal.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the string that is set to fixed is read only. Unless I malloc a memory and read from keyboard, the string(char *) can not be re-write. Thanks for all your help.